# landscape view not shows image and portrait show

Tags: android

I want to load image runtime in my activity but it is load in portait view only.
If I want to load it in landscape it doesn't.
I also do it by both seprate xml for landscape and portrait.
and also try by only one xml.
I draw image like this

```
   result_img.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.invalid_title));
```

But it draw in only portait layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

goto Manifest file and remove `android:screenOrientation="potrait"` attribute because it affect your app to view only in potrait mode only.if you have remove it you can show in both view. and one more thing is that you havent change any xml file